# Order By Count of Repeats On Top Of Other Order By

Tags: sql

I don't exactly know how to phrase this question but I was wondering how to achieve the output displayed below using sql:

Input Table:

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Output/Selected Table:

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

to explain what happened to the order it first sorted by ColA ascending. After this it then ordered each section based off of the count of times colB repeated in that section with the most repeated item being put ahead of the least repeated ones.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to complete the second ordering without taking the count of all repeats rather than just the ones in its given section.

here is my current code:
`order by ColA, count(*) over (partition by ColB) desc;`

Comment: Wouldn't you need to (partition by ColA, ColB) instead of just by ColB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't also partition by ColA the counts won't be based on the ordering of ColA.

```
order by ColA, count(*) over (partition by colA, ColB) desc;
```

provides your desired result.

Comment: Of course, this is much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am new to sql and don't have a great understanding of the partition keyword

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the database so I wrote a solution for PostgreSQL. You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
join (
  select cola, colb, 
    row_number() over(partition by cola order by count(*) desc) as rn
  from t
  group by cola, colb
) x on x.cola = t.cola and x.colb = t.colb
order by t.cola, x.rn
```

Result:

```
 cola  colb 
 ----- ---- 
 1     2    
 1     2    
 1     2    
 1     1    
 1     1    
 2     1    
 2     1    
 2     1    
 2     2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0932cb58690fb5f580c11669ffa44201).